# How to divide the first row of a table into two rows

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, align

I want to divide the text in the first row into two rows so my table will be on the A4 sheet. How I can do that?

I want to use a command other than p{dimen}

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{the speeding rate} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{speed by applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{speed without applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}   {c|}{Improvement of the speed} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{57} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{777} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8777} &     \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `p{<dimen>}` column specifier with appropriate `<dimen>`. Or use a `tabularx` or put the header in two rows by yourself.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{speeding rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.8cm}|}{\raggedright speed by applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5cm}|}{\raggedright speed without applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}   {p{2.6cm}|}{\raggedright Improvement of the speed} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{57} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{777} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8777} &     \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{86} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{80} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12} &   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the dimensions inside `p{2.5cm}` etc suitably. Further you can reduce the inter column space by using `@{}` such as

```
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}@{}|}{speeding rate} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.8cm}@{}|}{\raggedright speed by applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.5cm}@{}|}{\raggedright speed without applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}   {p{2.6cm}@{}|}{\raggedright Improvement of the speed} \\
\hline
```

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{5}{|c}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|X|} {\raggedright speeding rate} &  \multicolumn{1}{X|} {\raggedright speed by applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}{X|} {\raggedright speed without applying the algorithm} & \multicolumn{1}{X|} {\raggedright Improvement of the speed} \\
\hline
57 & 777 & 8777 &  1 \\
\hline
10 & 86 & 80 &   5 \\
\hline
7 & 2 & 12 &  9 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

By brute force:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|c}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|} {speeding}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|} {speed by applying} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|} {speed without applying} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|} {Improvement} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {rate} &   \multicolumn{1}{l|} {the algorithm} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|} {the algorithm} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|} {of the speed} \\
\hline
57 & 777 & 8777 &  1 \\
\hline
10 & 86 & 80 &   5 \\
\hline
7 & 2 & 12 &  9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How this looks with `booktabs` package and without the vertical lines? My preferred way is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l} {speeding}  & \multicolumn{1}{l} {speed by applying} &  \multicolumn{1}{l} {speed without applying} &  \multicolumn{1}{l} {Improvement} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{l} {rate} &   \multicolumn{1}{l} {the algorithm} &  \multicolumn{1}{l} {the algorithm} &  \multicolumn{1}{l} {of the speed} \\
\midrule
57 & 777 & 8777 &  1 \\
10 & 86 & 80 &   5 \\
7 & 2 & 12 &  9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use a command other than p{<dimen>}

Comment: @Harry What do you mean? I have added few possibilities.

Comment: is that possible to center the wording in both lines?

Comment: @Harry In last 2 examples? Yes! use `c` specifier: `\multicolumn{1}{l} {speeding} `. In others? Yes. Use `\centering` like: `\multicolumn{1}{|X|} {\centering speeding rate}`. Same for `p{}` column.

Answer (score 0):

A tabular may be an element of a tabular, so you can write in the place of your `the speeding rate` for example

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
the speeding\\
rate
\end{tabular}
```

(with fingers crossed).